# how to upload files in hadoop with hue or putty?

Tags: hadoop, hue

Hi How to upload files in hadoop ussing hue or putty. I am new to hadoop. i am not able to find my window directory, such as c:\,D;\ or window files system. if I want to upload the files in windows suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putty can't access your windows file system if you're connected to a remote machine in it. You will need to use Filezilla or Winscp to get the file to the Hadoop machine, then `hdfs dfs -put` from putty.

In the Hue Filebrowser, I believe you can drag and drops files into it, but there is also an upload version, maybe only in the latest versions, though

If you want to upload directly from Windows CMD, you must download Hadoop binaries and configure the core-site.xml configuration file appropriately for your Namenode address